# How to reduce the width of the bar in pygal if there is less than 2 bars

Tags: python-3.x, charts, pygal

I'm using pygal to draw charts. Whenever there are multiples bars coming up it renders the chart perfectly.  But when there are less than 3 bars than the width of the bar is too much how can we reduce the width.

[image: Example pic]